# How to update and delete the data at the same time Realtime Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I would like to update the status and delete the open at the same time.
[This is my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmfJB.png)

```
 private void loadOrders() {
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Orders> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Orders>()
                .setQuery(requests,Orders.class)
                .build();
        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Orders, AdminOrderViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdminOrderViewHolder viewHolder, final int position, final Orders model) {
                viewHolder.txtTableNo.setText("Table No:" + model.getTableNo());
                viewHolder.txtOrderId.setText(adapter.getRef(position).getKey());
                viewHolder.txtOrderStatus.setText(Common.convertCodeToStatus(model.getStatus()));

                //New event button
                viewHolder.btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view){
                        showUpdateDialog(adapter.getRef(position).getKey(),adapter.getItem(position));
                    }
                });

                viewHolder.btnRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view){
                        deleteOrder(adapter.getRef(position).getKey());
                    }
                });

                viewHolder.btnDetail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view){
                        Intent orderDetail = new Intent(RestaurantViewCompleteOrder.this,OrderDetail.class);
                        Common.currentRequest = model;
                        orderDetail.putExtra("OrderId", adapter.getRef(position).getKey());
                        startActivity(orderDetail);
                    }
                });

                viewHolder.btnBill.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view){
                        showUpdatePayment(adapter.getRef(position).getKey(),status,open);
                    }
                });
```

I wanted to update and delete at here

```
 private void showUpdatePayment(final String key,String status,String open) {
        Query mUpdate =requests.child(key).child("status").child("open");

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I want to update multiple child at the same time.

Comment: That's not a question. What's wrong with this code?

Comment: The code does not have any wrong. I just want show how to update the data in showUpdatePayment.

Answer (score 0):

```
HashMap<String, Object> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
dataMap.put("status", 1);
dataMap.put("open",FieldValue.delete());
```

update `dataMap` will update status and delete open

hope this will help